# Как добавить в шорткод вывод меток в алфавитном порядке?

Tags: php, wordpress, шорткод

Нашел шорткод выводящий метки сайта на отдельной странице.

```
function tag_cloud_shortcode($atts) {
   
  extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'cat' => ''
  ), $atts));
   
  $query_args = array( 'cat' => $atts, 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
  $custom_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
  if ($custom_query->have_posts()) :
      while ($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post();
          $posttags = get_the_tags();
          if ($posttags) {
              foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                  $all_tags[] = $tag->term_id;
              }
          }
      endwhile;
  endif;
   
  $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags);
  $tags_str = implode(",", $tags_arr);
   
  $args = array(
  'echo'      => false,
  'smallest'  => 10,
  'largest'   => 10,
  'unit'      => 'px',
  'number'    => 0,
  'format'    => 'flat',
  'order'     => 'count',
  'include'   => $tags_str
  );
  return wp_tag_cloud($args);
}
add_shortcode( 'tagscloud', 'tag_cloud_shortcode' );
```

Он выводит их в одну строку, друг за другом.

[image: вывод меток шорткодом]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы они располагались по алфавиту, т.е., например, заглавная буква А и под ней все тэги, начинающиеся на А. Заглавная буква B, под ней все тэги на B и так далее. Вот как здесь.

[image: вывод меток по алфавиту]

Comment: @insolor указывать тут ЯП совершенно не нужно. Нужна только метка `wordpress`.

Comment: Это не "подскажите", а "сделайте за меня". Подсказать можно что смотреть https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query